# Cannot iterate over a tensor with unknown first dimension when using TF Keras Attention Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the Attention class to implement the Seq2Seq text summarization model, and when creating this class, the above minor error occurred in the Attention class imported from the TF Keras class.

> Error: TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) in () 25
> decoder_lstm_output, decoder_h, decoder_c =
> decoder_lstm1(decoder_embed, initial_state=[encoder_h, encoder_c]) 26
> ---> 27 att_output, att_state = Attention()([encoder_output, decoder_lstm_output]) 28 decoder_concat_output =
> Concatenate(axis=-1)([decoder_lstm_output, attn_out]) 29

```
    decoder_input = Input(shape=(None,))
    decoder_embed = Embedding(y_vocab_size, embedding_dim, trainable=True)(decoder_input)
    
    decoder_lstm1 = LSTM(300, return_state=True, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.4)
    decoder_lstm_output, decoder_h, decoder_c = decoder_lstm1(decoder_embed, initial_state=[encoder_h, encoder_c])
    
    att_output, att_state = Attention()([encoder_output, decoder_lstm_output])
    decoder_concat_output = Concatenate(axis=-1)([decoder_lstm_output, attn_out])
TypeError: Cannot iterate over a tensor with unknown first dimension.
```

Comment: Attention layer returns only one outputs not 2

Comment: The issue is solved in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289566/keras-attention-layer-on-sequence-to-sequence-model-typeerror-cannot-iterate-ov